# How to take character at specific index from each line?

Tags: linux

I need to extract and print 3rd character in every line of the text file using Linux. Do I use for loop to read each line and echo{var:3:1} to print each character out?

```
Input:
Hello
World
How are you




Output:
l
r
w
```

Comment: `cut -c 3 input.txt` cuts the third character in every line for you.

Comment: @lewis4u Honestly, mostly because I feel silly trying to expand 18 characters into an answer. :P

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use this command:

`cut -c 3 file_name.txt`

The cut command in UNIX is a command for cutting out the sections from each line of files and writing the result to standard output. It can be used to cut parts of a line by byte position, character and field. Basically the cut command slices a line and extracts the text. It is necessary to specify option with command otherwise it gives error. If more than one file name is provided then data from each file is prefixed by its file name.

-c (column) argument is used to get the character at a specific column.

```
Hello
World
How are you
  ^ is the third column
```

source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cut-command-linux-examples/

Comment: I got it. thanks a lot.